# Gps ou triangulação de antenas - Como saber a precisão da localização?

Tags: android, gps, geolocalização

Tenho um app que utiliza a api Location e funciona certinho na maioria dos aparelhos, porem tem um que mesmo ligado o gps não funciona com precisão adequada( passa por cima das casa e nao na rua).

Pelo teste que fiz ele usa a triangulação de antenas mesmo com o gps ligado.

Alguém sabe se existe uma maneira de validar a qual o tipo de localização o aparelho esta usando.

Se for com uma precisão baixa(triangulação de antenas) posso a partir disso traçar uma rota entre dois pontos. Se não utilizo a rota que o gps mostrou.

Comment: Mesmo o GPS não tem uma precisão 100%, depende muito do sinal da região, e do aparelho que está usando. E o GPS não é o único sistema de localização, existem outros que podem ate ser mais precisos dependendo da finalidade.

Comment: Se você estiver usando a primeira posição que o sistema te retornar, as chances são altas que seja uma triangulação de antena, que é obtida mais rápido que o GPS. Você pode validar a origem pelo método `Location.getProvider()` ou então pela accuracy como o @ramaral explicou.

Answer (score 6):

Depois de obter uma [Location](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/location/Location.html) pode usar o método [getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) para obter a precisão estimada, em metros, dessa localização.

A precisão estimada é definida como o raio de 68% de confiança: se você desenhar um círculo centrado nesta latitude e longitude, com um raio igual à precisão, há uma probabilidade de 68% da verdadeira localização estar dentro do círculo.

Você pode usar esse valor para decidir se traça uma rota entre os dois pontos ou se utiliza a rota que o gps mostrou.

Quanto menor for o valor retornado pelo método `getAccuracy()` maior é a precisão da localização obtida.