# GPS oscilando mesmo estando em local fixo

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, mobile, ionic

Estou trabalhando em um app Ionic, com rastreabilidade, mas o sinal de gps oscila muito certa de 200m, mesmo estando em um lugar fixo, conhecem alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Em ambientes fechados é normal o GPS oscilar. Ele tem mais precisão em locais abertos.

Comment: Sabe alguma forma de eu simular um evento "estacionado" e voltar a capturar quando estiver em movimento novamente?

Comment: Pode ser que tenha uma forma mas eu particularmente desconheço, nunca tentei fazer algo assim.

Comment: Não tem como você saber se de fato está parado só pelo GPS. Uma possibilidade seria fazer um "arredondamento" de leituras anteriores, mas aí teria um atraso no movimento. Poderia condicionar o arredondamento a um acelerômetro (se não tiver aceleração por determinado tempo, considere que está parado). Lembrando que nesse caso, o simples fato da pessoa manusear um telefone (se o GPS for um telefone, claro) seria detectado como movimento. Ajudaria você [edit] a pergunta e dar um pouco mais de detalhes do que sua aplicação vai fazer e o tipo de GPS, para sugestões mais específicas.

Comment: Normalmente um smartphone não possui GPS. A localização se dá pelas antenas de telefonia móvel. Cada antena possui GPS e por meio de cálculos, que popularmente conhecemos por "triangulação de antenas", é determinado o local aproximado do dispositivo. E note que nem sempre é um local preciso, mesmo estando parado. Com GPS "de verdade" isso não é comum. Usamos o termo GPS para smartphones porque fica mais fácil do que dizer "triangulação de antenas" e comercialmente também esse termo não cola. Então ficou assim mesmo "GPS".

Comment: @DanielOmine, sua afirmação não está correta. Smartphones possuem localização por GPS sim. A localização pelas antenas é mais uma forma de derivar a localização, mas a que tem mais precisão é a do GPS. Baixe uma app chamada GPS Test no Google Play, ela mostra a posicao e o sinal recebido dos satelites de GPS. Sobre o GPS oscilar mesmo estando parado, é completamente normal: http://www.gpstrackersecurity.com/why-gps-drift-when-stationary/. Como o Bacco disse, a aplicação precisa lidar com isso de alguma forma, mas de longe é um problema trivial de resolver.

Comment: O que coloquei é que não existe um "GPS real" nos smartphones. É um pouco inferior a um GPS dedicado,. E existe o sistema de localização pela rede de telefonia (triangulação)... mas enfim, não é algo trivial para a pergunta.

Comment: @cantoni Se "de longe é um problema trivial de resolver", por que você não oferece uma resposta? Certamente iria ajudar ao AP e a outras pessoas no futuro. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, eu escrevi errado, queria dizer que de longe *não* é um problema trivial de resolver. Desculpe-me.

Comment: @cantoni Ah, ok. Entendi. rs Sem problemas.

Comment: @RenanCesar, sabe me dizer se o celular que você está usando aceita apenas o modo A-GPS (Assisted-GPS)?

Answer (score 2):

A precisão real de um dispositivo depende do chipset, da localização onde você se encontra ( em um lugar fechado, tende se a ser mais impreciso), entre outras.

A precisão típica de um dispositivo GPS de mão seria algo como 30% das suas medidas no prazo de 50 metros da posição real (sim, os dispositivos são imprecisos).

Para tentar minimizar, você pode levar em consideração apenas as posições mais precisas!

Segue um exemplo:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  if(crd.accuracy < 25){
      // usamos apenas as com presição menor que 25 metros
   }  
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

**EDIT**

**enableHighAccuracy** : O atributo `enableHighAccuracy` fornece uma dica de que o aplicativo gostaria de receber os melhores resultados possíveis. Isso pode resultar em tempos de resposta mais lentos ou no aumento do consumo de energia. O usuário também pode negar essa capacidade, ou o dispositivo pode não ser capaz de fornecer resultados mais precisos do que se o sinalizador não foi especificado. A finalidade pretendida deste atributo é permitir que os aplicativos informem a implementação de que eles não exigem correções de geolocalização de alta precisão e, portanto, a implementação pode evitar o uso de provedores de geolocalização que consumam uma quantidade significativa de energia (por exemplo, GPS). Isso é especialmente útil para aplicativos que funcionam em dispositivos alimentados por bateria, como telefones celulares.

**accuracy** : Este indica o nível de precisão das coordenadas de latitude e longitude. É especificado em metros e deve ser suportado por todas as implementações. O valor do atributo accuracy deve ser um número real não negativo.

No exemplo acima, pegamos apenas as coordenadas com um precisão menor que 25 metros. Isto quer dizer que ele pode estar em um raio de 25 metros desta posição.

[Referência](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)

Comment: Não entendi duas coisas: 1) precisão menor quer dizer precisão maior? 2) qual é o intervalo (range) da precisão (seria de 0 a 100)? Enfim, tem certeza que não tá invertendo a lógica?

Comment: Relacionado: [Gps ou triangulação de antenas - Como saber a precisão da localização?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124462/2541)@LuizVieira

Comment: Olá @LuizVieira, editei a resposta pra tentar sanar suas dúvidas!

Comment: Boa! Ganhou o meu +1.